# Can I multiply both sides with a polynomial to eliminate the denominator?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this equation $\frac{x-1}{x+3} = 0$. Solving this one through cross multiplication would give me $x = 1$.

But, If I'm correct, we can also express this one as $\frac{x}{x+3} = \frac{1}{x+3}$. If I cross-multiply, I'd get $x = 1$ or $x = -3$. But if I multiply both sides with $(x+3)$ to remove the denominator, I'd arrive with the same answer from the first approach.

So, how should I tackle this one? Can I multiply both side of an equation with a polynomial to cancel a denominator?

Comment: You can multiply or divide both sides by an expression *with the caveat that the expression was not allowed to evaluate to zero*.  The final result you arrive at you need to consider with that caveat.  Here, multiplying both sides by $(x+3)$ you need to state clearly that $x+3$ cant equal zero to do so.  Of course, $x+3$ is equal to zero precisely when $x=-3$, explaining your additional solution you found which should have been discarded.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your observation is right. You cannot multiply in the second case. In such cases one should use common denominators and set the numerator equal to 0.

Comment: @cgss "*you cannot multiply*" that is incorrect.  It is often terribly useful to multiply and cancel out... but you need to keep track of the fact that you did and that it may have accidentally introduced extra solutions.  Compare this to the question of finding for what values of $x$ you have the equation $x=1$.  It is clear to see that the only value of $x$ satisfying this is $1$, but let us ignore that for a moment and manipulate this anyways... multiplying both sides by zero.  We have that $x=1\implies 0=0$... and every value of $x$ satisfies the equation $0=0$.

Comment: The point is that the solution set that we see for this final equation does not necessarily match the original because we did something which is not reversible (*multiplying by zero*).  $x=1\implies 0=0$ but $0=0\not\!\!\implies x=1$.  In the same way $\frac{x}{x+3}=\frac{1}{x+3}\implies x(x+3)=x+3$ but $x(x+3)=x+3\not\!\!\implies \frac{x}{x+3}=\frac{1}{x+3}$ in general.  It will happen to imply the reverse here if we were to include the condition that $x\neq -3$, but does not imply the reverse if it were the case that $x=-3$

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't disagree with what you say but based on the level of the question, no offence to OP of course, I think it's better to start with "cannot multiply - keep the denom" as the first step and later on add "you know what, you can discard the denom but remember that you did so".

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb:

$$\bigg\{x\ \bigg|\ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\bigg\}=\bigg\{x\ \bigg|\ f(x)=0; g(x)\neq 0\bigg\}$$

So yes, multiplying or dividing by an expression is fine, but you must discard all solutions to $f(x)=0$ when $g(x)$ is zero too.